# GLEW Shaders seem unsupported

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, shader, glew

This is odd. I wanted to implement shaders in my gl program.
But GLEW tells me that shaders are unsupported on my system:

```
//glut init and glew init ...

if (GLEW_ARB_vertex_shader && GLEW_ARB_fragment_shader)
    printf("Ready for GLSL\n");
else
{
    printf("Not totally ready :( \n");
    printf( "VENDOR = %s\n", glGetString( GL_VENDOR ) ) ;
    printf( "RENDERER = %s\n", glGetString( GL_RENDERER ) ) ;
    printf( "VERSION = %s\n", glGetString( GL_VERSION ) ) ;

    exit(1);
}
```

Also GLEW can't give me any information about my graphic card. The above code produces the following:

```
VENDOR = (null)
RENDERER = (null)
VERSION = (null)
```

I' m using a laptop with an Intel HD 3000 and a dedicated Nvidia gtm 525 which are both capable of using shaders.
I included all necessary headers (gl, glut and glew) in the right order (glew at first) and linked to all corresponding libraries (in the right order). (This is not the first time I'm using OpenGL and GLSL).

I also tried other OpenGL games from the Software Center and they worked. So the drivers should work properly.

(As you probably already guessed) I'm using freeglut, GL extensions wrangler, Ubuntu 14.04, codeblocks and g++.

What could be the problem? Where should I search for this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot query those strings before you have an active GLX context ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an OpenGL context and have it active. `glGetString` returning a null pointer means, you don't have no OpenGL context active.

Comment: Ah thank you. Now I get an output for the Vendor information. But the main problem still remains. It still says that shaders are unsupported. Also using `glCreateProgram()` gives me a `SIGSEV` error

Comment: Ooops I also called `glewInit()` before creating the context. Now everything works fine. Thanks.